# I created a .resx file, how do I reference it in my view page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC2.

I created a .resx file in a folder I created:

```
/Resources/
/Resources/en-US.resx
```

In the properties I set it to use the custom tool: `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`.

I compiled the project.

Now in my view page, how do I reference a resource?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In the properties I set it to use the custom tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator.

When you did this, Visual Studio generated a strongly typed class for it so that you can access the resources. So simply bring the namespace into scope:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="AppName.Somenamespace" %>
```

and then:

```
<%: Resources.FooBar %>
```

This assumes that you have a `~/Somenamespace/Resources.resx` and `~/Somenamespace/Resources.en-US.resx` files and so on:

[image]

Comment: So I did that, but it doesn't seem to be resolving.  Why do you have Resources.resx and Resources.en-Us.resx?  (default is usually english no?).  oh maybe b/c my folder is 'Resources' its causing some confusion in the naming?

Comment: @codecompleting, `Resources.resx` is your language neutral resources. Then when you want to provide localized versions you use `Resources.xx-XX.resx`. If English is your default language then indeed you don't need `Resources.en-US.resx`. As far as the `Resources` folder is concerned it might indeed cause some conflicts. In this case you could use for example `Resources/Messages.resx`.

Comment: should my designer.cs file also have the custom tool set? its empty right now for me.

Comment: @codecompleting, the designer.cs file is automatically generated by visual studio (normally). You should not modify it by hand. If it's empty there must be some problem. Try removing and recreating the RESX file completely. You should specify the PublicResXFileCodeGenerator setting for the RESX file.

Comment: well I added a name/value pair, but my designer.cs is empty.  Hmm..this doesn't seem to be working yet ...

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue. As far as I add a Resources file to a project, Visual Studio automatically generates the corresponding designer.cs file and when I add key/value pair it updates it.

Comment: @codecompleting, this doesn't matter. Works fine for me on VS2008 as well.

Comment: ok it worked, the only difference I can tell is I named the file Resources, maybe it was the .en-US cause something...